# React Native: Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): >=2.6.10

Tags: ruby, react-native, rvm

I have created a project with the latest version of react-native@0.72.0. Additionally, I have installed Ruby version 2.7.6 using rvm. However, whenever I open the project folder in the terminal, I encounter the following error:

> Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): >=2.6.10.

To address this issue, I have created a new project with react-native@latest and installed rvm. I then ran rvm use 2.7.6 in the project folder.

My questions are:

Is there any way to resolve this error?
Will this error cause any issues?

Comment: I have the same issue and didn't find any way to solve it. It doesn't seems having impact on RN development